# Why the ValueError Exception is raised?

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name="posts", null=True, 
               blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, 
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class ReplyPost(models.Model):
    reply = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="reply", null=True, 
            blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, 
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
def reply_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ReplyPostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            replypost = form.save(commit = False)
            replypost.reply = form.cleaned_data.get("reply")
            replypost.post = post
            replypost.created_by = request.user
            replypost.save()
            return redirect("post", post.id)

    else:
        form = ReplyPostForm()
        args = {
            'form': form,
            'post':post
         }
        return render(request, 'home/replypost.html', args)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
   #.....

   url(r'^home/questions/(?P<pk>\d+)/reply/$', views.reply_post, 
         name="replypost"),
   url(r'^home/questions/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post, name="post"),
]
```

**forms.py**

```
class ReplyPostForm(ModelForm):
    reply = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = ReplyPost
        fields = ('reply',)
```

The error:

```
ValueError. The view 'WebBoard.views.reply_post' didn't return an
  'HttpResponse' object. It returned 'None' instead.
```

I can't not understand what is wrong with the code..Please update me if the code above is not sufficient to understand.

Comment: Because if `if request.method == 'POST':` is True but `if form.is_valid():` is False, nothing is returned (which is implicitly `None`)

Comment: You have two return values for three possible states

Comment: You need to handle the else condition when form is not valid. It should return something in False condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to return an `HttpResponse` instance for the case when a request is `POST` but the form is not valid.

Looking at your code, try to move the last lines back one indentation level; that way everything that isn't a `POST` with a valid form will fall into that last return statement.

```
def reply_post(request, pk):
    post = ...

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ReplyPostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            return redirect("post", post.id)
    else:
        form = ReplyPostForm()

    args = {
        'form': form,
        'post': post,
    }
    return render(request, 'home/replypost.html', args)
```